# Comparing strings in a list and appending those that have the same first and last character to a new list

Tags: python

I'm in an Intro to Python class and was given this assignment:

Given a list of strings, return a new list containing all the strings from the original list that begin and end with the same character. Matching is not case-sensitive, meaning 'a' should match with 'A'. Do not alter the original list in any way.

I was running into problems with slicing and comparing the strings because the possible lists given include '' (empty string). I'm pretty stumped and any help would be appreciated.

```
def first_last(strings):
   match=[]
   x=''
   count=0
   while count<len(strings):
      if x[0] == x[-1]:
        match.append(x)
      x+=x
      count+=1
```

So, when given:

```
['aba', 'dcn', 'z', 'zz', '']
```

or

```
['121', 'NbA', '898', '']
```

I get this:

```
string index out of range
```

When I should be seeing:

```
['aba', 'z', 'zz']
```

and

```
['121', '898']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains an empty string (`''`). Thus, you will have to check for the length of each element that you are currently iterating over. Also, it does not seem that you use `x`:

```
def first_last(strings):
   match=[]
   count=0
   while count<len(strings):
      if strings[count]:
         if strings[count][0].lower() == strings[count][-1].lower():
            match.append(strings[count])

      count += 1
  return match
```

Note, however, that you can also use list comprehension:

```
s = ['aba', 'dcn', 'z', 'zz', '']
final_strings = [i for i in s if i and i[0].lower() == i[-1].lower()]
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what are you referring to when you write [count]?

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_last(strings):
   match=[]
   for x in strings:
      if x is '' continue;
      if x.lower()[0] == x.lower()[-1]:
        match.append(x)
   return match
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if the list element is not None first:

```
def first_last(strings):
    match = []
    for element in strings:
        if element and element[0].lower() == element[-1].lower():
            match.append(element)
    return match
```

or with list comp:
`match = [element for element in strings if element and element[0].lower() == element[-1].lower()]`